# Java - Repaint specific components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paintcomponent

I'm learning Java as part of my degree but its very brief but what ever I do I like to make sure I atleast have some understanding.

Until now anything that I want displayed on the screen is put into the `paintcomponent` method of the `JPanel`.

However, I have drawn out some parts of my layout which never change, and only a certain thing in the middle rotates.
I have a timer which calls `repaint()`.

If I correct in thinking that everything including the components that never change are being removed and then redrawn and the whole `paintcomponent` method is being run every time.

To me I feel like I should (or there must be) a way where the static stuff is moved out / is only drawn once, and only the parts that I specifically want to be redrawing should stay in the `paintcomponent` method?

Is this correct or am I not fully understanding something?

Answer (score 2):

- I  am assuming that you are not adding GUI components in the paintComponent method, right?
- Components are not "removed" during a repaint
- Better to put the stable part of any image into a single background BufferedImage and draw the BufferedImage in the paintComponent method. This can make for more efficient painting.
- Consider calling an overload of `repaint(...)` that sets a bounding rectangle for the region to be painted.

Comment: Inside paintComponent is just my Graphics stuff, filloval and transforms etc. The timer is incrementing a counter which is used as an angle in one of the transforms, which is the only thing that is changing but isnt everything else getting repainted also?

Comment: @binarysmacker: yes. That's why you should consider my rec's above.